# How to connect to remote couchdb database

Tags: python, couchdb

I am new in couchdb. I am running a python code in a server. This code stores data in a couchdb database. I want it to store the database in my computer. My code is very simple and the following one:

```
server = Server('http://125.151.58.68:5984/')
db = server['dnsrecords']
```

When I run this code , I get the following error messages:

```
File "dblookup.py", line 12, in main
    db = server['dnsrecords']
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/CouchDB-0.8-py2.6.egg/couchdb/client.py", line 137, in __getitem__
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/CouchDB-0.8-py2.6.egg/couchdb/http.py", line 377, in head
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/CouchDB-0.8-py2.6.egg/couchdb/http.py", line 419, in _request
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/CouchDB-0.8-py2.6.egg/couchdb/http.py", line 239, in request
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/CouchDB-0.8-py2.6.egg/couchdb/http.py", line 205, in _try_request_with_retries

socket.error: [Errno 111] Connection refused
```

Comment: You need to run the couchdb server?

Comment: By default, CouchDB listens only on 127.0.0.1.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Run `couchdb -c` to see where your config files are, and then edit the `local.ini` config file and uncomment and change the `bind_address` value to `0.0.0.0` so it's bound to all your IPs.

Comment: I have done what you recommend. Then, I try it with the following command in a machine : "curl http:// mycomputeripaddress:5984/"  The result : "curl: (7) couldn't connect to host".  Thanks for advice, and for any other ones

Comment: Just realized that I left out the step of restarting your CouchDB server, the instructions for this depend on your OS.  Maybe `/etc/init.d/couchdb restart` if your on Linux, or `killall -f beam.smp` if you're on OSX using launchd.

Comment: Also, CouchDB v2.* requires you to setup cluster/nodes, even if you desire a single node config, prior to actual usage.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, using version 3.1.1, modifying the local.ini file and default.ini didn't make any difference. I found a file called **10-bind-address.ini** inside folder **/opt/couchdb/etc/default.d** changed 127.0.0.1 to 0.0.0.0 and it worked.